# How to install the Django-Simple-Blog package into an existing Django project?

Tags: django, pycharm

I found a similar question, with this reply: "...django-simple-blog is an app, meaning you install it within an existing project."

But I need more explanation. Can someone explain to me how to "install" an app within an existing Django project? And what it means to do so? (I use Pycharm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django allows us to add multiple apps.

For eg.: if we want to add multiple social authentications, we can install `django-allauth`

install a thirdparty app

`pip install django-allauth` # or any other app you like.

or create a new one

`django-admin startapp simpleblog`

then we modify our `settings.py` in our django project.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'allauth', # add the app name here.
'simpleblog',
]
```

You can refer following to learn more about Django:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/
2. https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/
3. https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11